# Facebook Marketing api "read" function deprecation issue

Tags: php, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using php code for [fb marketing api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/v3.3) and facing this deprecation issue

> Deprecated: read is being deprecated, please try not to use this in new code.

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdAccountFields;

$account = new AdAccount('act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$account->read(array(
  AdAccountFields::TOS_ACCEPTED,
));

// Dump TOS Accepted info.
var_dump($account->{AdAccountFields::TOS_ACCEPTED});
```

Have they updated their code somewhere else? what should I use instead of `read` function? Thanks.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @HappyCoding version 3.3

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/4-30-2019-endpoint-deprecations

Comment: @atymic I think its for `graph-api` not `marketing-api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API successfully return the field about TOS, probably a deprecation of the SDK Library, try this (I take it [from an example in the repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/AdAccountNode.php)):

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
$access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
$app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>';
$app_id = '<APP_ID>';
$id = '<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>';
$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
$fields = array(
  'name',
  'tos_accepted',
);
$params = array(
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($id))->getSelf(
  $fields,
  $params
)->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 3):

The **read** function is deprecated from the SDK

You should use the **getSelf** instead of this.

They have mentioned this in the sdk files on line 277 of https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Object/AbstractCrudObject.php

```
  /**
   * @deprecated
   * use getSelf() instead
   * Read object data from the graph
   *
   * @param string[] $fields Fields to request
   * @param array $params Additional request parameters
   * @return $this
   */

  public function read(array $fields = array(), array $params = array()) {
   .....
  }
```

You can find documentation related to other deprecated functions over there.

Comment: @Zain, this should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks for your help, TheVigilant.

Comment: Matteo answer is also working and he posted earlier. Although I have upvoted